# My update query does not trigger AFTER UPDATE Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I write this:

```
update School set Name = Name where Id = 733021
```

My trigger declared like this work:

```
[dbo].[SchoolUpdateSomething] ON
[dbo].[School] AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
DECLARE @N int, @SchoolType nvarchar(255)
```

But if I do

```
update School set Name = Name
```

It will not trigger the trigger for all rows. Why?

I also saw the same problem while really updating the rows, for exemple by updating names with school names from another table:

```
UPDATE School
   SET Name = usl.Name
FROM School s INNER JOIN UpdatedSchoolList usl
   ON s.Id = usl.Id COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

Carl

Comment: Can you post the code for your trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/80432-statement-level-vs-row-level-triggers

You must take action yourself upon the rows in the INSERTED pseudo table.

Comment: I think I understand the problem, but not your solution. Could you detail?

Comment: In your trigger, you can access a virtual table whose name is "INSERTED" and execute DML upon the rows in it.

Comment: Great, another thing to discover! For this precise situation, I used a loop cursor to do that job.

Comment: @Malartre: you almost **never** really need a cursor..... try to avoid those like the plague - **especially** inside a trigger!